# Splash issue with https://sailing-channels.com/by-subscribers

Tags: scrapy, splash-screen

I'm attempting a scrapy-with-splash project to get a few fields off the website "https://sailing-channels.com/by-subscribers".   This site uses java to retrieve and delete listings as you scroll.
I've not had any luck getting the splash server to give me the whole set of data, or any of the detailed listings for that mater.

My first question is can splash even do this?

I really don't care how I get this data.  I would prefer doing it with a program but any tool that can get me fields from this site in an .csv file would do the job.  Anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks for any advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you want render it? They have pretty good API, check `https://sailing-channels.com/api/channels/get?sort=subscribers&skip=0&take=5&_=1548520116425`. So you can iterate, increasing `skip` argument and parsing json each time.
Looks like very promising way.